# Export non duplicated rows in 2 csv files

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have 2 csv files data1[649] rows, and data2[395] rows. Both have [30] columns. By comparing 13 of these 30 columns I can get 382 rows which appear in both files.
However, I tried to get the rows that do not appear in both files as follows:

```
merged = pd.merge(data1,data2,how='outer',
 on=["col1","col2","col3","col4","col5","col6","col7","col8","col9","col10","col11","col12","col13"], 
 indicator=True)

df_both = merged[merged._merge == 'both']
print(df_both)
df_left = merged[merged._merge == 'left_only']
print(df_left)
df_right = merged[merged._merge == 'right_only']
print(df_right)
```

The result is confusing as I expected `df_left` to be [267 rows x 14 columns]
but I got [275 rows x 14 columns]

same for `df_right` , I got [25 rows x 14 columns] instead of [12 rows x 14 columns]

Am I using it wrong or there is another way to extract non duplicated rows? Noting that I am getting the correct result for `df_both` [382 rows x 14 columns]

I already tried how= outer/inner/left/right, but nothing returned any expected result for df_left & df_right

Comment: See `how='outer'` parameter in first line, make it `how='left'`

Comment: Thank you, I already tried outer/inner/left/right, but nothing returned any expected result for df_left & df_right

Comment: can you provide some of your data from both of the dfs in question ? it will be good for us to provide solution.

Comment: Try to remove duplicates from data1,data2 before merging and let me know.

Comment: @k33da_the_bug thank you it works. I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

To isolate (and drop?) your duplicates, it depends on what kind of duplicates you've got. As told you k33da_the_bug, not easy without data.

But, the idea is:

If duplicates are just on values you can filter them with:

```
df[df.duplicated()]
```

If it's on index,

```
df[df.index.duplicated()]
```

And if it's on both

```
df[(df.duplicated()) & (df.index.duplicated())]
```

Assuming that df is your dataframe df_both. You can also apply it on left only or on right only if you want to operate separately.
But if you do so, you could possibly have duplicates again when merging.

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. I eliminated duplicates on indexes and I got what I want. I voted your answer but as a new user my votes wouldn't be shown as I don't have the needed reputations yet!!
Thanks again

Comment: Thank you Amr. That's kind of you. Really happy to know that it helped

Comment: @LumberJack Good answer, +1 from me : )